# how do I make 2 cells in two columns in html table unite

Tags: html

I have this code
that makes the table in the photo I added, how do I make one cell that will take the upper left and bottom left cell's place?

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>upper left</td>
      <td>upper middle</td>
      <td>upper right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bottom left</td>
      <td>bottom middle</td>
      <td>bottom right</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

[image: here is the image of the table i currently have]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) attribute

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">upper leftbottom left</td>
      <td>upper middle</td>
      <td>upper right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bottom middle</td>
      <td>bottom right</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```